# Vaadin Charts 2 shared tooltip example

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-charts

I need an example of a **shared tooltip** in Vaadin Charts 2. This means for one slot on the X-axis, multiple Y-axis values are shown together in a single tooltip box.

The Vaadin Charts Demo has a [`Lines with Complex Html tooltip`](http://demo.vaadin.com/charts/#LinesWithComplexHtmlTooltip) showing such a shared tooltip. Note how data points in both series (halos around red diamond and blue dot) are shown highlighted while a single tooltip box displays both data points’ values.

[image: Screen shot of example chart with a tooltip shared between two data points.]

An excerpt from the Demo’s displayed source code.

```
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip() ;
tooltip.setShared( true ) ;
tooltip.setUseHTML( true ) ;
tooltip.setHeaderFormat( "{point.key}" ) ;
tooltip.setPointFormat( "" ) ;
tooltip.setFooterFormat( "{series.name}: {point.y} EUR" ) ;
```

However, adapting that code to my own project fails. My X-axis is a date-time [`DataSeries`](http://demo.vaadin.com/javadoc/com.vaadin.addon/vaadin-charts/2.0.0/com/vaadin/addon/charts/model/DataSeries.html).

- **GOOD**
  The `point.key` successfully renders as a date-time string.
- **BAD**
  The `{series.name}: {point.y}` appears literally rather than being interpreted to render a value.

Perhaps someone can post a simple complete example?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copied the data from the Vaadin Charts Demo - however their source renderer has rendered the HTML. Have a look at [the original class in git](https://github.com/vaadin/charts/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/vaadin/addon/charts/examples/lineandscatter/LinesWithComplexHtmlTooltip.java):

```
tooltip.setHeaderFormat("<small>{point.key}</small><table>");
tooltip.setPointFormat("<tr><td style=\"color: {series.color}\">{series.name}: </td><td style=\"text-align: right\"><b>{point.y} EUR</b></td></tr>");
tooltip.setFooterFormat("</table>");
```